# dll.net no se encuentra progId

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo una `dll` la cual llamo desde otra aplicación (de escritorio). En mi equipo funciona todo correctamente. El problema es cuando intento realizar el procedimiento en otro quipo. Me arroja el siguiente mensaje al invocarla:

> No se puede encontrar el archivo especificado progId
>   "wsDataTransactions.dataTransactions"(progId de la dll)...

Al parecer es algo en el registro, ya que si yo descargo Visual Studio y compilo el proyecto en el equipo conflictivo desaparece el inconveniente. ¿Alguna idea?

La dll es invocada desde un ERP realizado en delphi. Este ERP busca la dll en todo windows, motivo por el cual en cualquier dirección la encuentra siempre y cuando esté en el equipo local desde el cual se abre el mismo. Coloco la dll en la carpeta C (podría ser cualquier carpeta) y registro la dll con `regasm.exe`. Ejecuto el ERP alojado en el servidor de desarrollo, invoca la dll y aparece el mensaje de que no encuentra el progId. Abro Visual Studio como administrador, compilo el proyecto en el equipo conflictivo, y no hago nada más, solo compilo. Vuelvo nuevamente al ERP y ya funciona.

Al parecer al compilar hay alguna llave que se crea en el registro, pero no logro identificar cuál sea. Ya verifiqué registrando la dll con regasm.exe pero las llaves son las mismas en el equipo del problema y el mío.

Comment: Es Asp o es aplicación de escritorio, si es de escritorio revisa que tengas la librería en la misma ruta que la tengas en la computadora principal, si es ASP revisa que en la carpeta bin del proyecto tenga la librería incluida.

Comment: Lo acabo de realizar y sigue el problema. Solo se soluciona registrando la dll y compilando el proyecto de la misma desde visual studio... Al parecer al compilar hay alguna llave que se crea en el registro... pero no logro identificar cual sea... Ya verifiqué registrando la dll con regasm.exe pero las llaves son las mismas en el equipo del problema y el mío...

Comment: vuelvo a preguntar ¿es en escritorio o es en Web?, la librería ¿esta dentro de tu proyecto o en una ruta especifica? en la máquina que falla, lo estas ejecutando desde visual VS o es el cliente

Comment: Es escritorio. Y es invocada desde un ERP realizado en delphi. Este erp busca la dll en todo windows, motivo por el cual en cualquier dirección la encuentra siempre y cuando esté en el equipo local desde el cual se abre el mismo.Coloca la dll en la carpeta C,(Podría ser cualquier carpeta) y registro la dll con regasm.exe. Ejecuto el erp alojado en el servidor de desarrollo, invoca la dll y aparece el mensaje de que no encuentra el progId. Abro visual studio como administrador, compilo el proyecto en el equipo conflictivo, y no hago nada más, solo compilo. Vuelvo nuevamente al erp y ya funciona

Comment: Hola @OmarPerezBeltran. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Cuando se agrega información relevante a la pregunta, conviene [edit] la misma. Los comentarios son para aclarar temas no relevantes para la pregunta en sí

Comment: Hice una prueba.. borré la carpeta bin después de compilar... y vuelve al error... es decir... si depende de una ruta... pero ... al parecer incluye la ruta con nombre de usuario y todo porque probé en otro equipó con la misma ruta e igual no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo leído en los comentarios deduzco El equipo que intentas usar no tiene permisos de administrador al registrar la DLL, pues dijiste:

> Abro visual studio **como administrador**, compilo el proyecto en el equipo conflictivo[...] Vuelvo nuevamente al erp y ya funciona

Lo que sucede es que al ejecutar la instrucción de registro de la librería desde el cliente(La máquina en conflicto), lo haces sin permisos de administrador y no se registra.

De ser esto así podrías crear un archivo .BAT con la siguiente linea de comandos

`REGSVR32 myDll.dll`

Que este en la misma ruta que la dll y ejecutas este como administrador.
de esta manera la Dll ya quedara registrada.

Intentarlo y comenta si funcionó.

Comment: Cuando registro la dll lo hago a través de cmd iniciando como administrador. Y ahí mismo indica que se registró exitosamente, es más, si voy a regedit y busco la llave, ahí se encuentran todas las clases de la dll registrada. De todas formas ya intenté con la línea que me indicas y continúa el problema. Cabe mencionar que en el quipo donde intento instalarla, tiene permisos de administrador, incluso el UAP está abajo totalmente.

Comment: El erp trabaj con activeX ... No sé si esto sirva para solucionar el inconveniente.